# Removing the Unmount Partition Disks Prompt During Unnattended Ubuntu Install

Tags: grub2, mount, unattended-upgrades

I'm trying to create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu and have removed *nearly* every possible prompt from the installation process.  The only remaining prompt is the one shown in the text below, which prompts me to unmount mounted partitions.  The annoying part is it doesn't matter to me whether I choose yes or no, so the whole prompt is pointless for my application.  Additionally nothing I have tried has prevented this prompt from appearing.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may prevent this prompt from ever bothering me again?

> The installer has detected that the following disks have mounted partitions:
>
> /dev/sda
>
> Do you want the installer to try to unmount the partitionson these disks before continuing?  If you leave them mounted you will not be able to create, delete, or resize partitions on these disks, but you may be able to install to existing partitions there.
>
> Unmount partitions that are in use?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the line of thinking from another answer but with a complete tested code example.

I was running into the same issue and finally by luck happened upon a set of slides that allowed me to automate this and there was an accompanying code repository with the full preseed file. https://github.com/uweplonus/adia-install/blob/master/initrd/preseed.cfg#L3

Many people suggest using `preseed/early_command umount /media/*` but this hasn't worked for quite some time due to the timing of when the preseed portion runs compared to the partitioning.

The correct way to do this is to add the following anywhere in your preseed file that is referenced by the boot command.

```
USBDEV=$(list-devices usb-partition | sed "s/\(.*\)./\1/");\
BOOTDEV=$(list-devices disk | grep -v "$USBDEV" | head -1);\
debconf-set partman-auto/disk $BOOTDEV;\
debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev $BOOTDEV; \
umount /media || true;
```

Comment: A huge +1 for this post. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to any experience about modifying the installation of Ubuntu.

But the most easiest (and possibly safest) thing would be to automatically umount every `/dev/sdXY` that is currently mounted, except the one with mount point at `/`. I've constructed the following bash command:

umount `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8 mount | grep -P '^/dev/sd' | grep -v 'on / type' | awk '{print $1}'`

---

To explain how it works, I'll split it up command by command:

- `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8 mount` lists the currently mounted drives in the following format, forcing an English locale:

  ```
  /dev/devicefile on mountpoint type filesystem (mount options)
  ```

  e.g.

  ```
  /dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
  proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
  sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
  ```
- `| grep -P '^/dev/sd'` lists the currently mounted deviced and takes every line from it which starts with `/dev/sd`, i.e. filtering for every solid disk device.
- `| grep -v 'on / type'` removes the live system root partition from that selection, so you won't unmount the installer itself ;)
- `awk '{print $1}'` Splits the single lines using any whitespace as delimiter, and returns the first element of the split line, which is the udev device file, so the output will look something like this:

  ```
  /dev/sda1
  /dev/sdb1
  ```

This output is finally passed to `umount` (must be run as root), which unmounts those partitions, allowing a safe installation without prompt.

Comment: This worked for me: `d-i partman/early_command string umount $(mount | grep '^/dev/sd' | grep -v 'on /cdrom type' | cut -f1 -d\ )`  In busybox the grep has no -P and there is no awk. Also, the install media was mounted on /cdrom

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, have to post it here.
Dragon788's solution worked for me well until I tried it on empty hard drive.
It gave me an error and and waited for input, so it wasn't fully unattended.
Maybe there's another way, but this helped me:

`umount /media || true;` 
instead of 
`umount /media;`
to supress error.

Comment: Good call, I think I've actually used this in one of the preseed files in the past, but I totally forgot to update it here. Upvote for helping me improve my answer!